# Summing up an unknown number of Integers in groups of 4

Tags: java, arraylist

my issue is that after running my code I realized that it's not going to cut it. It currently lists all elements of the studentName (string) arrayList and all elements of the studentGrade (double) arrayList.
The problem is, four grades are to be assigned to each student and each set of four grades must be summed up separately (then I will average them out). If I sum up all elements in the studentGrade arrayList... that's not going to be indicative of each student individually. Where should I go from here? I've been struggling to come up with options.

```
package arrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestGrades {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<String> studentName = new ArrayList<String>(); 
ArrayList<Double> studentGrade = new ArrayList<Double>();
boolean loop = true;

while (loop) {

    System.out.println(" Please Enter Student Name");
    String student = scanner.nextLine();

        if(student.equals("C"))
        {
          break;    
        }
        else
        {
          studentName.add(student);
        }


    System.out.println("Please enter Student Grade");
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

        Double grade = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
        studentGrade.add(grade);  
    }    

    System.out.println(studentName);
    System.out.print(studentGrade);
  }
}
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is: you enter a name and four grades; average those, empty the array, do it until you're done.

Comment: Okay, the issue is that the user can input any number of students. 4 grades will be entered per student. That means any number of grades could be entered. I don't know how to automatically add up an unknown number of grades, 4 grades at a time. Plus, those grades should be attached to the student somehow.

Comment: If they need to be "attached" to the student then you should attach them, either with a class as Andrew suggests, or with a simple map of student name => grades. But the *immediate* problem could be solved as I suggested. Because your requirements are vague I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry it is so vague. It is difficult to articulate what I'm trying to do. The user enters the students and 4 grades per student, not me. And they can enter any number of students. If it did not involve user input this would be easy for me.

Comment: Then pretend there's no user input: code a solution without it. *How* the data gets into the system is orthogonal to how it's processed.

Comment: For my assignment, there must be user input, and in the fashion shown. I get what you're saying by orthogonal, though

Comment: You've misunderstood. I'm saying that (a) *pretend* there's no user input. What would the data look like? How would it be processed? And (b) since processing the data is separate from *getting* the data, mold your user input to your processing. That aside: I already gave you a solution that'd take a single line of code to clear out the list after you've summed/averaged the current student's grades.

Comment: That's a great idea, Dave. Is the solution you are talking about making a map? And that would allow me to add up each group of 4 numbers separately?

Comment: Dave, the reason why averaging out the numbers as I go won't work, is because it won't satisfy the objectives for my assignment. All the data must be stored and displayed at once. Here's the last part of the assignment: "Next, display each student's name, average score and letter grade. The output should be sorted by student last name."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are in need of a Student class, which holds a student name and an array of the grades for that student. Then you can create a method in that class that sums up all the grades for that student and call that method as you loop over the List of Students.

---

Either that or a multi dimensional array where the students are one index and the second dimension is an array of grades for each index. Don't go this route unless it's a school assignment and you haven't learned about classes and OOP, because it's terrible to maintain and read.

Comment: Thank you. I'll have to look into how to create all that

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still so lost. Making a Student class is enticing, but the problem is, it seems I'd need a separate attribute for every set of 4 grades. Since this is user input, there could be any number of sets of grades. Is there a way to have the program automatically create a new array or arrayList whenever a new set of grades is entered?

Comment: @StevieJ321 You can create arrays whenever you want.

Comment: Yes, I can manually create as many as I want. But there would need to be a separate one for every group of 4 grades. So it seems like they'd need to be automatically generated when the user inputs a new student.